# ExtJs (v 6.0.0, classic) Message box with custom text and forms

Tags: javascript, extjs, dialog, modal-dialog

I want to have a workflow in ExtJs where I display a modal dialog in which someone needs to enter some data into a form and then presses the 'OK' to move on.

As far as I have seen the basic [Ext.MessageBox](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.MessageBox.html) could be a good fit in the first place.

But the documentation just describes a 'message' property. This one seems to be very restricted to me.

What I need is a custom form to be displayed as main body.
A custom form with three toggle buttons and a textarea.
Not some prefigured single and simple textfields or textareas.

How can that be done? - Is the Ext.MessageBox not the right item to use?

Building a modal window does not feel correct as well since there are a lot of configurations which need to be done on top.

Did I miss something? Is the problem understandable?

What I have so far:

```
Ext.Msg.show({

        title:'Title',
        message: 'Here we should see another form with 3 togglable buttons and a textarea...',

        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
        icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,

        fn: function(btn) {
            console.log('button: '+ btn)
            if ( btn !== 'ok' ) { return; }
        },
    });
```

[image: Dialog]

And this is somewhat what it should look like...

[image]

Of course it would be nice to react on the user's input after OK is pressed. Any hints are welcome as well.

Comment: Do you want to override this throughout application or particular module ?

Comment: I guess on a particular module. Not globally on the application. I have one certain, unique place where I want the dialog to be shown.

Comment: So for this you can create a common component that can be reusable at whenever you required. Using `Ext.window.Window`

Comment: Yes, I am on the track as well. So reusing a/the MessageBox is not the right way since I does not let me build a custom 'content' but rather gives me a predefined text-input or textarea. That's it.
I took a look at the MessageBox code which directly inherits from Ext.window.Window. And it somewhat solves my issue described here (but opens 20 others :-)
Thanks to all helpers and posters.

Answer (score 0):

I added showDialog function to window class by overriding it.

You can call showDialog by passing parentWindow and only parentWindow will be masked

```
showDialog: function(parentWindow) {
    var me = this;

    me.parentWindow = parentWindow;
    parentWindow.disableByMask();

    parentWindow.on({
        show: me.onParentShown,
        destroy: me.onParentDestroyed,
        hide: me.onParentHid,
        maskclick: me.onParentMaskClicked,
        scope: me
    });

    me.show();
},

disableByMask: function() {
    var me = this;

    me.setLoading("");
    me.loadMask.msgWrapEl.hide();

    var el = me.loadMask.getEl();
    el.setStyle({ opacity: 0 });

    el.on({
        mousedown: function () {                
            el.setStyle({ backgroundColor: "#CCCCCC", opacity: .5 });                
            me.fireEvent("maskclick", me, el);
        },
        mouseup: function () {
            el.setStyle({ backgroundColor: "#FFF", opacity: 0 });
        }
    });
},

hideDisabledMask: function() {
    var me = this,
        el = me.loadMask.getEl();

    me.setLoading(false);
    el.setStyle({ backgroundColor: "rgba(204, 204, 204, .5)", opacity: 1   });

    me.loadMask.msgWrapEl.show();
    me.loadMask.msgEl.show();
    me.loadMask.msgTextEl.show();
},

onParentShown: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.show();
},

onParentDestroyed: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.close();
},

onParentHid: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.hide();
},

onParentMaskClicked: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.zIndexManager.bringToFront(me);
},

onDestroy: function() {
    var me = this;

    if (me.parentWindow) {
        me.parentWindow.hideDisabledMask();
        me.parentWindow.un("show", me.onParentShowed, me);
        me.parentWindow.un("destroy", me.onParentDestroyed, me);
        me.parentWindow.un("hide", me.onParentHid, me);
        me.parentWindow.un("maskclick", me.onParentMaskClicked, me);
    }

    me.callParent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  Ext.MessageBox, you have to create a customized pop up window with 3 buttons and a text area as **items** and a **tbar** button with text **OK**. For that button you have to use handler for your necessary actions i.e..,

```
tbar =[
    {
        text: 'Ok',
        handler: function() {
            var textAreaValue = Ext.getCmp('text-area-id').getValue();
        }
    }
];
```